# Why doesn't this property work on the following composite function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition, rational-functions

Given $f(x),g(x)$ find $(f \circ g)(x)$.

$$f(x) = x + \frac 1x \\g(x) = \frac{x+1}{x+2}\\(fog)(x) = \frac{x+1}{x+2}+\frac{1}{\frac{x+1}{x+2}} = \frac{x+1}{x+2}+\frac{x+2}{x+1}$$

Using the property $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$ I now get: $$\frac{(x+1)^2+(x+2)^2}{(x+2)(x+1)} =(x+1)(x+2)$$

But that is incorrect. The correct answer is: $$\frac{2x^2+6x+5}{(x+2)(x+1)}$$ I understand how this was reached, but I'd like to know what was wrong with the application of that property? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Indeed, I suspect it's a cancellation issue: $(x + 1)^2 + (x + 2)^2$ is *not* a multiple of $(x + 1)$ nor $(x + 2)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The property works.

$$\frac{(x+1)^2+(x+2)^2}{(x+1)(x+2)}=\frac{x^2+2x+1+x^2+4x+4}{(x+1)(x+2)}=\frac{2x^2+6x+5}{(x+1)(x+2)}$$

I believe your careless mistake is $(x+1)^2+(x+2)^2 \neq (x+1)^2(x+2)^2$

Comment: Ah! Thank you. That's exactly where I went wrong.